# PHP How to convert array into csv using fputcsv function

Tags: php, csv

please I have the following array :

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "lkjhgj"
    [1]=>
    string(16) "jhgjhg@jhgjj.com"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "hgjk,"
    [1]=>
    string(18) "kjhgfghj@dgdfg.com"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "dddd ffff"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "dddd@gmail.fr"
  }
}
```

I want to put it into a csv file, so I've tried :

```
$fichier = 'file.csv';
$fp = fopen($fichier, 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) 
{
   fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);

header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$fichier);
```

But when I download the file I found it empty !

Please masters any idea ? Thanks in advance

PS : Permissions are 777

Comment: Where does `$list` come from in your code example? What's in there?

Comment: I don't see any code that actually returns the file as part of the response!  After you've closed the file it's got to be reopened before you can send it.  Also I don't see any error checking in your code, fopen, fputcsv and other file operations can fail.  You need to check that they've not returned FALSE

Comment: use `$fp= fopen('php://output', 'w');` instead of `$fp = fopen($fichier, 'w');`.. see my answer below

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
 $fichier = 'file.csv';
 header( "Content-Type: text/csv;charset=utf-8" );
 header( "Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"$fichier\"" );
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 header("Expires: 0");

 $fp= fopen('php://output', 'w');

 foreach ($list as $fields) 
 {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
 }
 fclose($fp);
 exit();
```

Comment: I tried this code. I am getting a corrupted csv file. Could not open the file. Please help.

Comment: Please include an educational explanation to this code-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving array in session and issues of encoded characters.

```
session_start();
$fp = fopen($_SESSION['CSV']['type'].'.csv', 'w');
foreach ($_SESSION['CSV'] as $fields) {
    $val1 = htmlspecialchars_decode(utf8_decode(html_entity_decode($fields[0], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8')));
    $val2 = htmlspecialchars_decode(utf8_decode(html_entity_decode($fields[1], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8')));
    $val3 = htmlspecialchars_decode(utf8_decode(html_entity_decode($fields[2], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8')));
    fputcsv($fp, array($val1,$val2,$val3,$val4,$val5));
}
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

if somebody is looking for exporting the results from a query with dynamic headers to an array then to csv file you could use the following function :

```
function exportCSVFile($fieldsNames, $result)
{

$fileName = "result.csv";
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$stdout = fopen('php://output', 'w');

fputcsv($stdout, $fieldsNames, ',', '"'); // put the headers or fields Names

$resultArray = array();

$tempRowHolder = array();

/* 
    build the finalized array which will be used to export the result as csv 
*/

for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($fieldsNames); $j++) {
        $tempRowHolder[$j] = $result[$i][$fieldsNames[$j]]; // fetch a row by the different fields names
    }

    /* push the row from the tempRowHolder array to the main array($resultArray) */
    array_push($resultArray, $tempRowHolder);

    /* clear the temporary array (the holder of the row) to use it fresh in the next iteration */
    $tempRowHolder = [];
}

$i = 0;

/* put the finalized array into the csv file  */
while ($i < count($resultArray)) {
    fputcsv($stdout, $resultArray[$i++]);
}

fclose($stdout);
}
```