# How to write csv file and open in MS.Excel in charset UTF-8

Tags: php, excel, csv

I have detect my value to write is Thai language and I will write to CSV file but when I use `fwrite` and save .CSV file and open this CSV file in Excel.I see my text about "เธฅเธนเธเธเธฅเธดเนเธ,เธชเธฃเนเธฒเธเธฅเธฒเธข" Below this code

```
$xfile =fopen($filename,"w");
foreach( $data as $itm ){
     $outstr="";
     foreach($itm as $key=>$str){
            $val =str_replace("\r\n","",$str);
            val =str_replace("\t\t","",$val);
            $val =str_replace('"',"'",$val);
            $outstr=$outstr.'"'.$val.'"'.$clm;
            //dump(mb_detect_encoding($outstr));die(); --Result UTF-8
     }
$outstr=substr($outstr,0,strlen($outstr)-1);
fwrite($xfile,$outstr."\r\n"); //Newline
fclose($xfile);
```

I feel stupid Or i forgot something. Please help

Comment: Use a library to write csv/excel file properly. https://github.com/PHPOffice

Comment: @Mark can you give me some example for symfony framework?

Comment: you can browse sample directory. https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/develop/samples/Basic/16_Csv.php

I'm not using symfony but installing phpspreadsheet with composer, using its namespace and calling it should work. try it in your controller first. Ived been using it for how many years. Its best for spreadsheets like csv.

Comment: @Mark Thanks a lot man.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809133/php-how-to-convert-array-into-csv-using-fputcsv-function/14809209#14809209

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use BOM with UTF-8 and insert after value. I see from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25729859/3802190)

```
$xfile =fopen($filename,"w");
$BOM = "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM
fwrite($xfile, $BOM);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try mb_convert_encoding before you write.

```
$xfile =fopen($filename,"w");
foreach( $data as $itm ){
     $outstr="";
     foreach($itm as $key=>$str){
            $val =str_replace("\r\n","",$str);
            val =str_replace("\t\t","",$val);
            $val =str_replace('"',"'",$val);
            $outstr=$outstr.'"'.$val.'"'.$clm;
            //dump(mb_detect_encoding($outstr));die(); --Result UTF-8
     }
$outstr=substr($outstr,0,strlen($outstr)-1);
$outstr= mb_convert_encoding($outstr, "UTF-8");
fwrite($xfile,$outstr."\r\n"); //Newline
fclose($xfile);
```

Check detail here [PHP_mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)